# Java bitwise comparison of a byte

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a value DB of 3 bytes (DB_1, DB_2, DB_3).
I need to check DB_3 for specific bits. For example I have to see if
 `DB_3 == 11X0XXXX`
Where only bit 4, 6 and 7 should be checked. Bits marked as `X` can take any value and should not be checked. I am not familiar with Bit operations in Java and glad for any help!
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a bitwise AND (`&` in Java) to accomplish the masking to specific bits (the mask is the second line and will only let those bits of the first line through where the mask has a `1` [marked with arrows below the calculation]):

```
  11101001
& 11010000
----------
  11000000
  ↑↑ ↑
```

You'll retain exactly those bits that were `1` in both operands, so essentially you set all those bits to `0` that you are not interested in.

So you just need to do

```
if (DB_3 & 0xD0 == 0xC0) { ... }
```

`0xD0` is the hexadecimal form of `208` which is `11010000` in binary and you want to know whether it matches `0xC0` which is `192`, or `11000000`. You'll know that all the bits you don't care about (the `X`es in your question) are already zero at this point due to the bitwise AND.

---

**ETA** (2011-12-14 14:24): Apparently Java 7 has [binary integer literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html), so you can do

```
if (DB_3 & 0b11010000 == 0b11000000) { ... }
```

which makes the mask more readily apparent. Thanks, [Glenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726422/glenn).

Comment: I guess Java 7 has binary literals: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Answer (score 7):

You have to use *Masks*. You do a bit operation with the value and the mask.
The result will contain only the bit if it was set in the value.

http://www.divnull.com/lward/writing/bitwise.html

Answer (score 5):

While Joey's method works just fine, here's another way to do it which I personally think feels more intuitive.

You will need two masks: `MASK1 = 11000000` which defines how `DB_3` is supposed to look, and `MASK2 = 11010000` which defines which bits should be taken into account. `1` bits in `MASK2` indicate bits we care about and `0` bits indicate bits we do not care about.

Do an XOR with `MASK1` and invert that, then an AND with `MASK2`, and check if the result equals `MASK2`. The first two operations will place `1`s where `DB_3` and `MASK1` match. The third operation will drop all digits in the result to `0` except for the bits indicated by `1`s in `MASK2`. The comparison evaluates to `true` if and only if `DB_3` matches `MASK1` at the positions indicated by `1`s in `MASK2`.

```
int MASK1 = Integer.parseInt("11000000", 2); // tell parseInt to use base 2
int MASK2 = Integer.parseInt("11010000", 2);
boolean matches = (~(DB_3 ^ MASK1) & MASK2) == MASK2;
```

Example of the bitwise operations:

```
  11101001
^ 11000000
----------
  00101001
~
----------
  11010110
& 11010000
----------
  11010000
```

I hope that was understandable.

Comment: I'd probably add the exact bitmasks as comments instead of using `parseInt`, but that may be personal preference (and yes, the comments could go out of date). But Grenn pointed out that there are binary literals in Java by now which makes it certainly look more natural.

Comment: If I were to do this "for real" I'd probably compute the decimal representation and add a `//208d = 11010000b` comment or something like it. The use of `parseInt` here was mostly for clarity, and that I didn't think of using such a comment at the time...

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to C. Check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html